# Dynamic SQL with choosing multiple dropdowns in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hie I'm new to ASP.Net and needed some help.

Here is my problem: I have 4 drop downs in my application, a button saying search, grid view to show the results. I was trying to filter the results based on the value of drop downs.

So i wrote the query as "select * from table where column1=dd1.SelectedItem.Value" but the tricky part is i want the results to be displayed even if one of the drop down is selected or two of them is selected or all of them is selected. How do i write the Where Part in my SQL query?? I know that I have to use dynamic SQL but i have no clue about dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
            string q = @"
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
(@value1 IS NULL OR column1 = @value1) 
AND
(@value2 IS NULL OR column2 = @value2) 
AND
(@value3 IS NULL OR column3 = @value3) 
";

            var command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = q;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", dd2.SelectedItem.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", dd3.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you i have tried it but it doesnt recognize @value1 parameters i am getting an error..

Comment: Add the code that you are using so I can help you out

Comment: I have tried com.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, v); too but the error is "The parameterized query '(@value1 varchar(100),@value2 varchar(100),@values3 varchar(100),' expects the parameter '@value1', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

First you should store **dd1.SelectedItem.Value** in a variable as

```
string v = dd1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

then create a string for your query as

```
string q = "select * from table where (column1 is null or column1=" + v + ")";
```

then use this code:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(q, yoursqlconnection);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: This is open for SQL Injection attacks. Do not use this. Do no concatenate paramters' values in  sql query strings.

Comment: I know but s/he is a beginner. S/he should use entity framework.

Comment: S/he could also use procedures and functions with the parameters but s/he wants to concatenate parameters' values in sql query strings.

Comment: I understand SQL injection and im using Parameterized query but my point is to write a where condition when the values of all the drop downs are null and even if only few are null..

Comment: You can write `column1 is null or column1=`

Comment: If column1 is varchar you should say `com.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, v);`

Comment: Or `column1='+v+"'"`